# Получение значения атрибута "name" тэга "input"

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как получить значение атрибута `name` всех тэгов `input`?

То есть если был тэг

```html
<input name="value">
```

то в массиве должно быть только значение "value".

Я знаю, что для `div`'a это можно сделать так:

```
titles = [div['title'] for div in soup.find_all('div', title = True)]
```

Но если пробую просто заменить все `div` на `input`, а `title` на `name`, то сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что `input` - зарезервированное слово (возможно, проблема не в этом, но все равно ничего не работает)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
input_names = [tag['name'] for tag in soup.select('input[name]')]
```

Проверка:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

rs = requests.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830858/')    
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

input_names = [tag['name'] for tag in root.select('input[name]')]
print(input_names)  # ['q', '_id_', 'qualityBanWarningShown', 'referrer', ...
```

Answer (score 3):

> если пробую просто заменить все div на input, а title на name, то сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что input - зарезервированное слово

Этой проблемы точно нет:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<input name="value">', 'html.parser')
>>> [input['name'] for input in soup.find_all('input')]
['value']
```

Хотя `input` и является встроенным именем, поэтому не рекомендуется его использовать для своих целей, чтобы путаницу не вводить, но локально (как в примере с listcomp) читаемость от использования `input` не уменьшается. Всегда можно другое имя использовать, если хочется:

```
>>> [tag['name'] for tag in soup.find_all('input')]
['value']
```

Можно вообще без временных имён обойтись:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter('name'), soup.find_all('input')))
['value']
```

Вы вероятно наткнулись на ошибку с использованием `name` параметра:

```
>>> soup.find_all('input', name=True) # XXX broken
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: find_all() got multiple values for argument 'name'
find_all() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

ошибка из-за того, что `name='input'` и `name=True` передаются в `find_all()` одновременно. Это легко обойти:

```
>>> soup.find_all('input', dict(name=True))
[<input name="value"/>]
```

или для читаемости:

```
>>> soup.find_all('input', attrs=dict(name=True))
[<input name="value"/>]
```

Если вы знакомы с [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors), то можно [как @gil9red предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/830892/23044):

```
>>> soup.select('input[name]')
[<input name="value"/>]
```